# Why main generation template is named psvm in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-templates

[According to help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/generating-main-method-example-of-applying-a-simple-live-template.html), main generation template is named `psvm`.

Why didn't they name it just `main`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an acronym:

**p**ublic **s**tatic **v**oid **m**ain

But 'main' works fine too.